# Python package Expiring Dict is not working (automatic expiring)

Tags: python, dictionary, time, python-3.10

Using the following [package](https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/) for expiring dictionaries doesn't work. Is there any known deprecation on the package? The GitHub repository seems inactive but the latest release was 1 and half years ago.

If the package is indeed deprecated, is there a well-known replacement?

```bash
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from expiring_dict                          import ExpiringDict
>>> denms = ExpiringDict(max_age_seconds=3)
>>> denms["john"] = "doe"
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(10)
>>> print(list(denms.items()))
[('max_age_seconds', 3), ('john', 'doe')]
```

Comment: `expiring_dict` (from https://pypi.org/project/expiring-dict/) is not `expiringdict` (from https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/).

Answer (score 0):

From the package's PyPI page:

> Note: Iteration over dict and also keys() do not remove expired values!

IOW, I think you'd find that `denms["john"]` would not return a value:

```
>>> import expiringdict
>>> d = expiringdict.ExpiringDict(max_age_seconds=1, max_len=100)
>>> d["foo"] = "bar"
...
>>> d["foo"]
KeyError: 'foo'
>>>
```

Or, for the other similarly named package:

```
>>> import expiring_dict
>>> d = expiring_dict.ExpiringDict(1)
>>> d["foo"] = 10
>>> d["foo"]
KeyError: 'foo'
>>>
```

Comment: Just tested, it does return